# Google Sheets: Those rows are out of bounds error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am brand new to writing code and I am fumbling through this trying to come up with a spreadsheet that is fed info from a form. I have searched and searched for the answer to this problem for days but I cannot figure it out on my own without some help..so HELP! :)

What my script does it creates a copy of a sheet based on a trigger every night so that I have a record of form responses for each day. I want to to delete (not clear) all rows except the top 6 rows each time a new sheet is created so the form will add lines each time a response is given. I keep getting the ***Those rows are out of bounds. (line 17, file "DailyClear")*** when I try to run the script.

Here is what I've got

```
function dailyclear(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Today');

  sheet.copyTo(ss)
  var nusheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Today')
  var value = nusheet.getRange("B2").getCell(1,1).getValue()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(nusheet)

  Logger.log("Current index of sheet: %s", nusheet.getIndex())
  ss.moveActiveSheet(2);
  nusheet.setName(value);

  //Clear "Today"
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.deleteRows(7, lastrow-6)

  //Set Date Value for "Today"
  var dd = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yy");
  sheet.getRange("B2").getCell(1,1).setValue(dd);
}
```

It will not allow me to delete the 7th row and retain rows 1-6 without throwing that error if the 7th row is blank and the only row that exists. If I start adding information from form responses in the cells and it starts creating rows and I run the script it throws up the error ***Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows. (line 17, file "DailyClear")***. And on top of all that when a new sheet is created I have the 7th row clear ready for the first response from the form to fill and the form puts the first response of the day on row 8 and leaves 7 blank! This is driving me crazy...anyone recommend a good book for beginners before I go crazy? :(  Thanks for any help I can get, here is a link to my sheet..

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NZxXjMptx6ldzL2CKk6OwJcq_heIv995ZGVeIE59xNc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you to anyone who can help

Comment: `Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows. (line 17, file "DailyClear")` This is a normal behavior, if you have frozen rows you cannot delete all the unfrozen rows. You cannot change this behavior, try doing it manually it will give you the same error. You will have to leave an empty in the non-frozen row or get rid of the frozen row completely. As to why the new values are getting added to row 8, you will have to post the code that transfers the data to determine what is going there.

Comment: I would post the code but I honestly don't know where to get it....sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already, you cannot delete all non-frozen rows, so Row 7 will have to stay. Perhaps shrink it down and add a fill or some formatting so it just doesn't look like an empty row, and then since data is entered on row 8 anyway, change your script slightly to accomodate:

```js
function dailyclear(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Today');

  sheet.copyTo(ss)
  var nusheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Today')
  var value = nusheet.getRange("B2").getCell(1,1).getValue()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(nusheet)
    
  Logger.log("Current index of sheet: %s", nusheet.getIndex())
  ss.moveActiveSheet(2);
  nusheet.setName(value);
  
  //Clear "Today"
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()
  sheet.deleteRows(8, lastrow-7);
  
  //Set Date Value for "Today"
  var dd = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yy");
  sheet.getRange("B2").getCell(1,1).setValue(dd);
}
```

Comment: Ok I get it, I don't know why it didnt register with me that it was saying exactly what it meant and I have to have at least one non-frozen row existing. And I like the idea of just shrinking row 7 and making it a non-factor, great thinking there! Quick question though, if no responses are given on the rare occassion and the script runs there will be no row 8 and it will give the error for Those rows are out of bounds. Is there something I can put in there that IF no row 8 exists, to just create a new copy for the next date and skip the deleterows section?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to wrap that in an if statement.