# Google Apps Script function gives error "Exception: Those rows are out of bounds." when deleting rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to automate a task for my team at work, and I am having some trouble with the function below named "clearData". Pretty much everything about the automation works as intended, except that if a user presses the button that calls the "clearData" function and there is no data on the sheet, it throws an error

> Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.

and stops the function, which means it does not hide the RXFORM sheet as intended.

What am I doing wrong here that is causing this? I have created an IF statement that should keep the row deletion from even happening if there is no data there, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any input is appreciated. I am an amateur, script-kiddy style coder who usually uses these things to automate simple tasks for myself and my coworkers.

```
//a function that resets the formula on the form submission sheet to ensure that it does not have any errors.

function setFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("READY TO PRINT");
  ss.getRange("A1").setFormula('={"SOURCE:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!B2:B))}');
  ss.getRange("B1").setFormula('={"ACCT:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!C2:C))}');
  ss.getRange("C1").setFormula('={"CLIENT:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!D2:D))}');
  ss.getRange("D1").setFormula('={"PET:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!E2:E))}');
  ss.getRange("E1").setFormula('={"REQUESTING:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!F2:F))}');
  ss.getRange("F1").setFormula('={"VISIT:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!G2:G))}');
  ss.getRange("G1").setFormula('={"LABS:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!H2:H))}');
  ss.getRange("H1").setFormula('={"HWT:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!I2:I))}');
  ss.getRange("I1").setFormula('={"INPUT DATE:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,RXFORM!A2:A))}');
  ss.getRange("J1").setFormula('={"DR:";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(RXFORM!A2:A),,"___"))}');
};



//a function that clears all the data from the form submission sheet, then hides the sheet from the user again. it also runs the setFormula function for good measure.

function clearData() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RXFORM");
  sheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  sheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();

  var last_row = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex() + 1;

  if (last_row >= 2) {
    sheet.deleteRows(2, last_row);
  }
  sheet.hideSheet();
  setFormula();
}
```

Comment: I'd try to remove the `+1` in this line `var last_row = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex() + 1;`

Comment: What do you mean by "form submission sheet"?

Comment: @Rubén When you link a Google Sheet to a form, it submits those completed form results as a row in a specific sheet in Google Sheets. That is the sheet that I am referencing. I am using the ARRAYFORMULA() function to pull those results into a more formatted sheet that can be printed for the veterinarians to be able to read easily. 

I want the user to be able to submit their online pharmacy request details for X amount of requests for the day, print that sheet for the doctors, and then clear out the data when the sheet is returned for approval.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. All the relevant details should be included in the question.

Comment: @Rubén, I am sorry if there was a relevant detail that was not included in the question, or if the language I used in the question needed clarification for you. Are you suggesting that I should have edited the question rather than comment in response to you? I'm not sure the exact purpose of your last statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to find the last row of the data range use the `getLastRow()` method of Class Sheet, in other words, instead of what is being done to declarte the `lastRow` variable use:

```
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
```

By the other hand to delete the rows from the 2 row to the last row, use

```
sheet.deleteRows(2, lastRow - 1);
```

The above because the second argument of `deleteRows` is the number of rows to be deleted. The error that the OP script is throwing is very likely that occurs because the `lastRow` is returning the last row of the sheet, but since the row deletion starts on row 2, the number of rows to be deleted is greater the the number of rows of the sheet.

Related

- [Google Sheets: Those rows are out of bounds error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43713078/1595451)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. When I try replacing those lines with the suggested code, I get the error that it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows.

Comment: @CSRSOMVH I think that the message is clear enough. One option is to unfreeze the frozen row, another option is to use `clearContent` instead of `deleteRows` (as was suggested in the other answer)

Comment: removing the frozen row at the top of that sheet seems to have resolved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something simpler:

```
function clearData() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName("RXFORM").getRange("A2:J")
  .clearContent();
  .hideSheet();

  setFormula();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!

I believe that this would not work for my current solution because I am using a Google Form to submit the data. If I just clear the content, then it will make the next submission on row X instead of restarting on row 2. I need the data to start being input back at row 2 after running clearData(), therefore I am using deletion. I might be incorrect on that

Comment: Sorry, it's something beyond me. As a last resort I'd try to add `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush before deleting the rows of somewhere else